# News Ticker Widget, How do they work?

Tags: android, widget, rss-reader

I know this is likely a silly question all things considered but I was wondering if anyone knew how a news ticker widget works... Is it just an RSS feed that displays on the screen or is it a webView that grabs the latest news from XYZ site?

Been trying to figure this out for a while...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually answered your own question.

An RSS feed is indeed among the simplest ways of doing it since most news websites have an RSS feed. Simply retrieve the feed and parse the XML blocks (i.e., title, news body, etc) and arrange the content the way you want it.

Since you've tagged Android, [give this a try](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html).

Comment: Thanks, this has not really been bugging me appwise but just an "I wonder how kind of thing!"